# C# While Loop keeps reusing the first user input;

Tags: c#, while-loop, user-input, repeat

As many here have said, I am a very new programmer, attempting to learn the basics so that I can have some skills under my belt for the future. I am watching the channel9 videos on C# by Bob Tabor, and am learning a ton, but when I started to proceed on my own, I have discovered there are some things I don't understand. I am writing code for a very simple text game, and I am well aware my code may be messy, or redundant, or both.

That being said, it executes flawlessly for what I wanted it to do, save one minor hiccup. If I input in the beginning Yes or no, it continues well enough. The problem is the option for if the user inputs something incorrect; I want them to receive a message stating to say yes or no, then to go back to the beginning and try again. But when it executes through, gets that message, and goes back, it will simply reapply the input from the first time, and I'll get stuck in an infinite loop. I know where the problem is, but being as inexperienced as I am, I am not sure how to fix the problem. I will try to copy/paste my code so you can see my problem.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace FirstSoloAttempt
{
  class Program
  {
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
      bool incorrectAnswer = true; //if user inputs anything other than yes or no, reloop to beginning
      Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play a game?");

      string answer1 = Console.ReadLine(); //somehow, need to allow this input to be changed second time

      while (incorrectAnswer)
      {
        if (answer1.Contains("yes"))
        {
          incorrectAnswer = false;
          Console.WriteLine("Great! Let's begin. Which door is the new car behind? It is behind door 1, door 2, or door 3?");
          string answer2 = Console.ReadLine();

          if (answer2.Contains("door 1"))
          {
            Console.WriteLine(" Your new car is a new 2016 Chevy Corvette! Congratulations!");
            Console.WriteLine("Are you satisfied with your new car?");

            string answer3 = Console.ReadLine();

            if (answer3.Contains("yes"))
            {
              Console.WriteLine("Fantastic!");
            }
            else
            {
              Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry you are not satisfied. You may return it for a different car.");
            }
          }
          else
          {
            Console.WriteLine("Oh! Bummer! You didn't win. Thanks for playing!");
          }
        }
        else if (answer1.Contains("no"))
        {
          incorrectAnswer = false;
          Console.WriteLine("Alright then! Goodbye!");
        }
        else
        {
          Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. Please answer with yes or no.");
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Basically, my code won't allow me to receive new input in order to change the result of the program loop. I know ti has to do with the code reading the input from the first string, answer1, so how can I change it for all following attempts?

Thanks for any help in advance! Coding is quickly becoming interesting to me, and the community of others helping out is a big positive.

Comment: I think you should create some sort of loop to keep checking the user's input. And then it will keep re-assigning the user input to `Console.ReadLine()` again.

Comment: Side note: You should probably have better conditions than using `Contains()` for everything. For instance, "My eyes are melting!" could be taken as "yes" and "Can I take notes?" could be taken as "no". I would use `answer1.Trim().ToLower().Equals("yes")`.

Comment: I didn't think of that, @JohnSensebe. That is a valid point. however, seeing how I really won't be using this in life at all, just for my own learning of how C# coding works, I probably won't change it at this point. I will definitely remember that tip for later though! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your `Console.ReadLine` inside th while loop is never assigned to anything.

Change

```
 Console.ReadLine();
```

To

```
answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: There's nothing in the posted code that prompts the user to input an value for `answer1`.

Comment: This also seemed to have worked, and allow the user to input new info. how? does this simple change at the end cause the user to re-input the value, or is this creating a new input...or third is it simply refreshing the user input because its in the while loop? I apologize for my naivety, but I am grateful for your patience in helping me learn!

Comment: You were already reading a new user input by calling `Console.ReadLine();`. The problem was that you were never assigning the new input to anything. `answer1 = Console.ReadLine();` assigns the new input to the `answer1` variable that you previously declared. Because this is in the `while` loop it will continue to refresh until the conditions for exiting the loop are met. Does this help clarify things?

Comment: Yes, yes it does! Thanks so much! To be honest, I didn't have that last Console.ReadLine in there because it would keep the console open to read all that had happened (my video instructor always does it to keep the processes on screen to show us what is happening). Now, I understand that it refreshes the content as it is rewritten until the parameters are met. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You should probably use something like this within your main void. This would allow you to keep reading the input until the user types something containing "yes".

```
string answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
while (answer1.Contains("yes") != true)
{
    answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
}
```

This would probably be a good solution because once you re-assign the variable for the answer, it wouldn't have to be hard-coded for the next response and would continue until your client has typed "yes".

Answer (score 0):

A do-while loop is more suitable for your case.

```
do
  {
    string answer1 = Console.ReadLine();
    //your existing code from while loop ...
  }while(incorrectAnswer)
```

Comment: I have been reading on do-while loops, but I am still a bit fuzzy on how this differs from a regular while loop. In my case, how would it change the output if I had used a do-while?

Comment: The main difference is that in do-while loop first is executed loop body only after that loop condition is checked, while in a  while loop fist thing is to check loop condition.

Comment: In your case by moving string answer1 = Console.ReadLine(); at the beginning of the do-while assures that if your loop condition is not fulfilled then it will be reexecuted. In this way you will have just one assignment statement of the answer1 instead of 2 like it will be in case of the while loop. By the way, I saw that I've miistyped in my initial answer variable name answer1 with answer2. I've corrected that.

Answer (score 0):

Just add change your else statement into the following

```
else
{
      Console.WriteLine("I'm sorry, I didn't understand that. Please answer with yes or no.");
      Console.WriteLine("Do you want to play a game?");

      answer1 = Console.ReadLine(); 
 }
```

Comment: This worked! Im curious, however, as to how it worked. If I simply paste this code into mine, it works, but I don't understand how. does that           answer1 = Console.ReadLine(); allow the user to change the original, or does it simply create a new instance of input for the console to read?

Comment: @vidathan You simply weren't getting a new input for answer1 so it just kept reusing the previous input. So answer1 = console.readline(); simply takes in the user input and stores the input as answer1. Also if this solved your problem please mark as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

The latter `Console.ReadLine()`is not changing the state of the first variable

change to `var answer1 = Console.ReadLine();`